# Number of unique CIELab colors in an image

Tags: python, matlab, colors, cielab

I have an image represented in the CIELab color space. How can I return the number of unique CIELab colors the image contains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique(...,'rows')`:

```
n = size(unique(reshape(img, [], 3)),1);
```